# Como obter as coordenadas (X e Y) de um click em um imageview?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, imagem

Estou fazendo uma aplicação que possui uma imagem que ocupa todo o  `ImageView`, e quando o usuário clica em algum ponto nessa imagem, são obtidas as coordenadas X e Y correspondentes a imagem e é desenhado um círculo com centro nesse ponto.
Considerando que minha imagem possua o seguinte tamanho (e por consequência o `ImageView`, que por padrão no Android, possui seu tamanho determinado pelas dimensões da imagem):

```
imgView.width = (int) (screen_width * 0.8);
imgView.height = (int) (screen_heigh * 0.8);
```

Utilizando o método do `ImageView`

```
imgView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        real_x = (float) (event.getX());
        real_y = (float) (event.getY());
        //desenhe um círculo com centro em Point(real_x,real_y) na imagem contida no imgView
    }
}
```

O problema, é que `event.getX()` e `event.getY()` não retornam as coordenadas reais, correspondentes ao ponto clicado na imagem. Sendo assim necessária uma conversão, **mas como fazer essa conversão de uma forma que seja válida para qualquer tamanho de tela?? **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`event.getX()` e `event.getY()` retornam as coordenadas em relação ao canto superior esquerdo da *ImageView*.
Como as dimensões da *ImageView* podem ser diferentes da imagem que ela contém, é necessário fazer uma conversão para obter as correspondentes coordenadas em relação à imagem.

Partindo do principio que a imagem foi atribuida à *ImageView* através de `android:src` as coordenadas podem ser calculadas da seguinte forma:

```
//Obter o Bitmap associado à ImageView 
Bitmap bitmap=((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

//Obter as dimensões do Bitmap e da ImageView
double bitmapWidth = bitmap.getWidth();
double bitmapHeight = bitmap.getHeight();
double imageViewWidth = imageView.getWidth();
double imageViewHeight = imageView.getHeigth();

//calcular a razão entre as dimensões do Bitmap e da ImageView
double ratioX = bitmapWidth / imageViewWidht;
double ratioY = bitmapHeight / imageViewHeight;

//Aplicar a razão às coordenadas
int bitmapX = (int)(x * ratioX);
int bitmapY = (int)(y * ratioY);
```

Onde `x` e `y` são as coordenadas obtidas a partir de `event.getX()` e `event.getY()`;

Comment: Obrigado pela atenção! Já que o tamanho do imageView será o mesmo do bitmap nele inserido através de `android:src`, qual a necessidade de fazer a conversão entre tamanho do bitmap e tamanho do imageview ? ratioX e ratioY não serão 1?

Comment: Sim e nesse caso as coordenadas que procura são aquelas retornadas por `event.getX()` e `event.getY();`. Assim sendo não percebo o que quer dizer com *"event.getX() e event.getY() não retornam as coordenadas reais"*

Comment: Como é *"que o tamanho do imageView será o mesmo do bitmap nele inserido"* se o tamanho da *ImageView* é ajustada a 80% do tamanho da tela?

Comment: Você não estará a confundir coordenadas reais com coordenadas absolutas? Coordenadas reais são em relação ao *Bitmap*, coordenadas absolutas são em relação à tela e coordenadas relativas são em relação à *ImageView*

Comment: Então, sendo assim eu preciso redimensionar meu bitmap para `bitamp.width = (int) (screen_width * 0.8);`
`bitmap.height = (int) (screen_heigh * 0.8);`

Comment: como o imageView se adapta ao tamanho do `src`, se por exemplo `src` fosse uma imagem 320x240, se eu fizer `LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) imageView.getLayoutParams();` `params.widht` e `params.height` teriam que ser 320 e 240 respectivamente, mas retornam -1 e -1. Para que funcione normalmente, esses valores tem que ter o tamanho real da imagem, visto que funciona normalmente quando eu faço `params.width=320; params.height=240;   imageView.setLayoutParams(params);`

Comment: Se você tiver os dois *layout params* como `wrap_content` a *ImageView* terá a dimensão real da imagem mas **não** pode obtê-la no `onCreate()` veja esta [pergunta](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10411975/2556111), no entanto no método `onTouch()` já devem estar disponíveis. Eu ainda não percebi qual o tipo de coordenadas que você quer obter, se são as reais, as absolutas ou as relativas.

Comment: Obrigado. Finalmente consegui, o problema era que o imageview estava iniciando com as dimensões diferentes da imagem. O que eu fiz foi, antes de tudo, carregar a imagem em uma matriz (Mat() - com OpenCV) com tamanhos personalizados (80% da tela) e após isso, passar as dimensões para o imageview.

Answer (score 0):

Experimente também obter as coordenadas a partir do canto superior esquerdo da sua imagem, assim você terá a referência exata:

```
int[] viewCoords = new int[2];
imgView.getLocationOnScreen(viewCoords);
```

E então, no `onTouch`:

```
real_x = event.getX() - viewCoords[0];
real_y = event.getY() - viewCoords[1];
```